# Why doesn't n jump to the last character matched with f?

Tags: vimscript, cursor-motions

I have a vim script that does the following:

```
normal 3f,
normal lvnh"+y
```

But if I search for anything other than `/,/` before hand, the `n` in `normal lvnh"+y` matches whatever I searched for last instead of the intended `,`.

So why does it do this, and how do I get it to search for a `,` instead?  Not a search and replace, but just a search for a `,`?

Comment: why do you want your `n` to do anything else? I think you need to search again for `/,/` before using `n`

Comment: @Nobe4 Because I want to say on the same line and select to the next `,`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want to **stay** on the same line ?

Comment: @Nobe4 Yes, I'm in a CSV and trying to switch to visual mode and select from the character I'm at to the next matched `,` in the line.

Comment: @leeand00 I think you confused `n`  which allows to repeat the last search made via `/` and `;` which allows to repeat the last `f` movement.

Comment: @Nobe4 Yup I didn't know they were different.  Thank you.  Post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but you should thanks @statox instead ;)

Comment: Well tell him to post then...@statox post your answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You confused `n`which repeat the last search (made via `/` or `?`) and `;` which allows to repeat the last `f`, `F`, `t` or `T` movement.

As a bonus `n` and `;` go forward while `N` and `,` go backward.

See [`:h n`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#n) and [`:h ;`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#;) as references.